# Obtener datos de una query en negación, MYSQLi PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

En esta query

```
SELECT * FROM definicion_modalidades A
INNER JOIN generica_modalidades B ON B.id_modali = A.id_modali
WHERE B.id_tienda=24;
```

Me devuelve esto

[image: captura]

Necesito saber si desde la query puedo obtener lo contrario a este resultado es decir, aquellos registros definición_modalidades que no estén en ningún registro con id_tienda 24.

Debería pensar en hacerlo desde la query o desde alguna función posterior? Harían falta más datos sobre las tablas para mejor entendimiento?

EDITADO: Pretendo mostrar un select combo con definicion_modalidades que no estén asignadas a esa id_tienda 24.

definicion modalidades
[image: definicion modalidades]

generica_modalidades
[image: generica_modalidades]

Comment: `WHERE B.id_tienda!=24;`

Comment: @alanfcm me devuelve todos los pesos y longitudes de los otros registros, necesito filtrar eso también, quizá con DISTINCT, pero no acaba de ser correcto.

Comment: en tu publicación solo haces referencia a lo que alan te recomiendo, si necesitas aplicar mas filtros entonces deberías editar tu pregunta y explica a a detalle lo que deseas hacer, del mismo modo colocar un ejemplo de datos de entrada y una muestra de los datos de salida que esperas obtener

Answer (score 0):

He encontraod la forma gracias a ***NOT IN***. Espero que pueda servirle a alguien.

```
SELECT A.id_modali,A.nombre_modalidad,B.id_moda FROM definicion_modalidades  A 
LEFT JOIN generica_modalidades B ON A.id_modali = B.id_modali
WHERE A.id_modali NOT IN 
(SELECT C.id_modali FROM generica_modalidades C WHERE C.id_tienda = 24);
```